# Segmentation fault when using std::fill

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run the following code, but it is giving me segmentation fault :-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 1000
int dp[MAX][MAX];

string s1, s2;

int lcs(int i, int j)
{
    int val;
    if ( i < 0 || j < 0)
        return 0;
    else if (dp[i][j] != -1)
    {
        return dp[i][j];
    }
    else
    {
        val =  max(lcs(i-1,j), lcs(i, j-1));
        if ( s1[i] == s2[j])
            val = max(lcs(i-1,j-1) + 1, val);
    }
    dp[i][j] = val;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    int tc;
    scanf("%d", &tc);
    while (tc--)
    {
        fill(&dp[0][0], &dp[MAX][MAX], 0);
        cin>>s1;
        cin>>s2;
        printf("LCS = %d\n", lcs(s1.size()-1, s2.size()-1));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Now, it is giving me a segmentation fault, at the `printf` line in while loop. However, if I comment out the fill statement, then there is no segmentation error.
What could be a possible reason for this ?

Comment: _"What could be a possible reason for this ?"_  Undefined behavior most probably. Wasn't able to spot it from your code sample.

Comment: Why use C++ strings and then fixed size C arrays and macros? Use vectors which can be the required size and won't break for large inputs.

Comment: Also seriously: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I mostly use bits/stdc++.h only in programming competitions where speed matters, not in actual programming projects.

Comment: @ps06756 How does that improve speed actually?? It shouldn't matter, even not for compilation time needed. That's a myth, if it was stated somewhere.

Comment: ...isn't `&dp[MAX][MAX]` quite a bit farther than one past the end of the array? Isn't it a past-the-end pointer for the past-the-end array, not the past-the-end of the last array?

Comment: @jaggedSpire That may indeed be the answer.

Comment: No, recursion is not causing the stack to overflow, I have confirmed it by passing very small inputs to the function and I was not talking about compilation speed but typing speed, and not having to bother about which class is in which header file.

Comment: Your program doesnt crash for me. Where are you running this? Environment? compiler?

Comment: I am running this using g++ 4.9.2 with flags -Wall and -g for debugging information

Comment: I am running on g++ 4.8.2 with/without -g3 flag. And it doesnt crash in both cases

Comment: @jaggedSpire Indeed that is the problem, I should have used `&dp[MAX-1][MAX]` . Please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it .

Comment: Technically I'm not sure if it's correct to use `[]` with one past the last element. You may need to use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
&dp[MAX][MAX]
```

This references the past-the-end pointer of the past-the-end array. You want the past-the-end pointer of the last array, instead:

```
&dp[MAX-1][MAX]
```

otherwise it's going to iterate over the past-the-end array, causing a segfault.